# Node/Sequelize/MySQL with TS - finding all column by dynamic query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Here is the table -

[image]

For example I want to get all `BTCUSDPrice` fields by query that I get from client the query is the same as the column name.

The only finder for finding all fields in sequelize is `findAll` like this -

```
await Crypto.findAll();
```

There is the `where: { }` option the field is not dynamic.

So is it possible to get all `BTCUSDPrice` fields by dynamic query?

Comment: do you only need the values of `BTCUSDPrice` attribute from the query

Comment: @cmgchess no, I need to use one of the three options I'll get in req.query.currency

Comment: `await Crypto.findAll({
  attributes: [req.query.currency]
});` if you want all the values of the column